# Some questions about the mysql timestamp field

Tags: java, mysql

I try to insert a record.
I found a problem with
When the server's time zone is greater than the time zone set by the database.
timestamp will automatically convert the data in that field. As shown in the image
I insert this record at 11-10 00:51am ,server  time zone is +8

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiuLO.png)

But conversely, when the server's timezone is less than the timezone set by the database, it does not convert

I insert this record at 11-09 21:56pm ,server time zone is +5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bv3HM.png)

I am using java for testing, the orm framework is jpa, and I am using jdbc to connect mysql

Someome could tell me why?

Comment: Please ignore the first time field and just look at the last one.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```java
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 
    … , 
    ZonedDateTime
    .of( 
        LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.NOVEMBER , 10 ) , 
        LocalTime.of( 0 , 51 ) , 
        ZoneId.of( "Australia/Perth" ) 
    )                                                  // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
    .toOffsetDateTime()                                // Returns a `OffsetDateTime` object.
)
```

… and …

```java
myResultSet.getObject( 
    … , 
    OffsetDateTime.class 
)                                                      // Returns a `OffsetDateTime` object.
.atZoneSameInstant( 
    ZoneId.of( "Australia/Perth" ) 
)                                                      // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
```

## Details

**Do not trust your tooling** to report true values as retrieved. Some tools have the anti-feature of applying a time zone after retrieving a date-time value from the database. Well-intentioned, but very confusing.

A `TIMESTAMP` column in MySQL 8 always stores values adjusted to UTC. That means an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds ahead or behind the UTC meridian. Per [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html):

> MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval.

Always **specify your desired [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)** or offset-from-UTC. Never rely implicitly on default time zone within Java, within your database connection, or within your database server.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Hong_Kong" ) ;
```

Always use *java.time* classes. **Never use the old `Date`, `Calendar`**, `SimpleDateFormat` classes.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.NOVEMBER , 10 ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 0 , 51 ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z ) ;
```

To send to the database, convert from a time zone to a mere offset via the [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) class, to be compatible with SQL.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = zdt.toOffsetDateTime() ;
```

If you want to see the value that will be eventually stored in the database, adjust offset to zero.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = zdt.toOffsetDateTime().withOffsetSameInstant( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Send to database.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieve from database.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

Adjust to a time zone.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;  // Same moment but viewed through the wall-clock time of a particular time zone.
```

You mentioned using [JPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Persistence) (now known as [*Jakarta Persistence*](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/)). The latest versions of JPA fully support the *java.time* classes. Tip: To experiment and learn how this all works, skip JPA and do some direct JDBC calls as practice.

All this has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.

Comment: Nice tip ...To the OP: you can learn more about the modern Date-Time API of Java from [this](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html) link and [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) link.

Answer (score 0):

How is your time_zone parameter on your MySQL server? you can check it with this query:

`SELECT @@time_zone`